# Remove signature in letters

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2, signatures

How can I remove the signature in KOMA-script scrlttr2 letters?

`\setkomavar{signature}{}` or completely deleting the line just leaves me with empty brackets `()`.

Comment: Please show the code (without personal informations) you tried so far!

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your issue:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
%\setkomavar{signature}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Max Mustermann}
\opening{Hey,}
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

results with and without `\setkomavar{signature}{}` in

[image]